# Django: Put multiple widgets/fields into one field

Tags: django, forms, widget, field

I'm making a form to let users edit their photo gallery. So when I show the form I need 2 fields/widget per photo.

For each photo there will be one 
`CheckBox(label='Delete photo', value=<Id of photo>)`
and one `RadioSelect(label='Set as cover image', value=<Id of photo>)`

In the form class I guess I should put something like this in the `__init__`:

```
for image in images:
    #make a checkbox widget
    #make a radio select
    #store the url of the image
    self.fields[..] = gallery_field_widget
```

I would prefer to put as much code in the form class instead of the template. I've played around with MultpleSelect widget but I can't figure out how to iterate through it together with the rest of the widgets.. and help on this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't two widgets per field, this is two fields per form and one form per instance. For that we have [formsets](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/forms/modelforms/#model-formsets).

Comment: Okey. Further, how can I attach all these formset to a ModelForm? I have a modelform of a 'project' model. The gallery is a foreign key to that project.

Comment: See [inline formsets](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets)